# Can't change Prerendered Icon Flag when uploading binary to iTunes Connect

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode4, xcode4.2, app-store-connect

So the problem is that in Xcode (v4.2.1) I have set `Icon Already Includes Gloss Effects to YES`, but every time I try upload my binary and check the binary details it says `Prerendered Icon Flag is FALSE`.

I had no problems with previous uploads of this app. The only difference is I changed the icon. So the new icon shows up fine once uploaded, but it has the gloss effect added, which previous versions do not have.

I have tried Cleaning first before build, tried setting Icon Already Includes Gloss Effects to NO, saving, closing xcode, re-opening, and then changing Icon Already Includes Gloss Effects back to YES, but uploaded binary always shows Prerendered Icon Flag is FALSE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so not sure why I was having the problem, but to solve this I had to close Xcode and go find the info.plist file and manually change the Prerendered Icon Flag to TRUE and now it is working agian fine.